# spring mvc: GET list of complex objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I started with mapping a collection of strings:

```
/abc?type=x,y,z
```

and I mapped that to a set of enums

```
@RequestParam(value = "type") Set<MyEnum> types
```

now I would like to add another parameter to each type. For example something like:

```
/abc?type=x:withProperty1,y:withProperty2,z:withProperty3
```

and ideally map it to list of some containers

```
@RequestParam(value = "type") Set<MyContainer> containers
```

and then:

```
class MyContainer {
   MyEnum type
   String property
}
```

Is it possible with Spring MVC? Or all I can do is just bind it to two different lists:

```
/abc?type=x,y,z&properties=withProperty1,withProperty2,withProperty3
```

Comment: Can you explain your issue briefly?

Comment: i need to extend existing API and pass list of pojos

Comment: Hi :) It will be useful for you .I searched for you .http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-controller-input.jsp

Comment: this example uses url `/persons?age=10` and doesn't show how to pass list of pojos inside url

Answer (score 0):

if you pass a parameters with the same name it will be converted to an array before arriving to your controller for Eg:

url ...`/somethig?type=x&type=y&type=z`

in your controller you have to define the request parametere as an array

```
@requestMapping(value="/something",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getTypes(@RequestParam(value = "type") String[] types){
  for(String type : types){
    System.out.print(type + "\t");
  }
}
```

as a result you will have

> x    y    z

so in your case you might use this solution.

url ...`/somethig?type=x&type=y&type=z&property=1&property=2&property=3`

in controller :

```
@requestMapping(value="/something",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getTypes(@RequestParam(value = "type") String[] types,@RequestParam(value = "property") String[] properties){
  for(int i=0;i<types.length();i++){
    MyContainer mc=new MyContainer();
    mc.setType(types[i]);
    mc.setProperty(properties[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, i was just hoping i can avoid manually checking if both lists have same size and building containers

Comment: can u add your form so i can provide you an other solution